# How to display one field from a JSON in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this JSON file:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5e4b1213e666de6628044139,
    product: 'air-jordan-1-retro-high-unc-chicago-leather-w'
  },
  {
    _id: 5e4b121de666de662804413a,
    product: 'nike-air-force-1-high-just-don-blue'
  },
  {
    _id: 5e4b1227e666de662804413b,
    product: 'air-jordan-new-beginnings-pack-1-nike-air-ship'
  },
  {
    _id: 5e4b1246e666de662804413c,
    product: 'nike-sb-dunk-low-strangelove-skateboards'
  }
]
```

I'd like to list all of the products all in one string. I noticed i can do `docs[1].product` but i want to do this for any amount.

I tried to do `docs.product` but the output is `undefined`

what i want is:

```
air-jordan-1-retro-high-unc-chicago-leather-w
nike-air-force-1-high-just-don-blue
air-jordan-new-beginnings-pack-1-nike-air-ship
nike-sb-dunk-low-strangelove-skateboards
```

Comment: Please update your question with sample output and your own attempt of doing it

Comment: edited to show clarification

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map` method and `join` method with required separator.

```js
const data = [
  {
    _id: "5e4b1213e666de6628044139",
    product: "air-jordan-1-retro-high-unc-chicago-leather-w"
  },
  {
    _id: "5e4b121de666de662804413a",
    product: "nike-air-force-1-high-just-don-blue"
  },
  {
    _id: "5e4b1227e666de662804413b",
    product: "air-jordan-new-beginnings-pack-1-nike-air-ship"
  },
  {
    _id: "5e4b1246e666de662804413c",
    product: "nike-sb-dunk-low-strangelove-skateboards"
  }
];

const productsLine = (data, seperator = "\r\n") =>
  data.map(x => x.product).join(seperator);

console.log(productsLine(data));
console.log(productsLine(data, ", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple possible way could be:

```
let result = [
    {
        _id: '5e4b1213e666de6628044139',
        product: 'air-jordan-1-retro-high-unc-chicago-leather-w'
    },
    {
        _id: '5e4b121de666de662804413a',
        product: 'nike-air-force-1-high-just-don-blue'
    },
    {
        _id: '5e4b1227e666de662804413b',
        product: 'air-jordan-new-beginnings-pack-1-nike-air-ship'
    },
    {
        _id: '5e4b1246e666de662804413c',
        product: 'nike-sb-dunk-low-strangelove-skateboards'
    }
].map(t => t.product);

// result is an array so lets see what to do with it
console.log(result.join('\r\n'));
```

Output:

```
> air-jordan-1-retro-high-unc-chicago-leather-w
> nike-air-force-1-high-just-don-blue
> air-jordan-new-beginnings-pack-1-nike-air-ship
> nike-sb-dunk-low-strangelove-skateboards
```